# Ayuda con función usleep en Linux C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una función que pausa la consola por unos segundos y luego continua a la siguiente función:

```
void esperar(double segundos){
    if(segundos < 0) return;
    #ifdef _WIN32
        segundos *= 1000;
        int goal = (int) segundos + clock();
        while(goal > clock());
    #else
        segundos *= 1000000;
        int goal = (int) segundos;
        usleep(goal);
    #endif
}
```

Suponiendo que quiero imprimir los números del 1 al 10 con un ciclo for obtengo dos respuestas diferentes dependiendo si hay un salto de línea o no.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    cout << i + 1 << " ";
    esperar(0.1);
}
```

En el primer ciclo dejo un espacio después de cada número, pero este ciclo espera una decima de segundo (0.1 * 1000000) por cada **cout** en el ciclo, sumando un total de 1 segundo. Sólo hasta que se terminan los 10 ciclos de 0.1 segundos se imprime la cadena.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

En el segundo ciclo dejo un salto de línea entre cada número.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    cout << i + 1 << endl;
    esperar(0.1);
}
```

Pero esto tiene un comportamiento diferente (y el deseado). Después de imprimir el primer **cout** la consola espera 0.1 segundos para imprimir el segundo cout, espera 0.1 segundos e imprime el siguiente....

```
1
//0.1 segundos
2
//0.1 segundos
3
//0.1 segundos
4
//0.1 segundos
5
//0.1 segundos
[...]
```

Tengo las siguientes librerías incluidas

```
#include<time.h>
#include<unistd.h>
```

¿Existe una manera de corregir esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la primera versión utilizas como separador un espacio:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    cout << i + 1 << " ";
    esperar(0.1);
}
```

Lo que sucede aquí es que estás acumulando en el buffer de salida una secuencia de números. Que los acumules en el buffer de salida no implica que se estén mostrando en pantalla. El buffer no es síncrono con la consola.

En un momento dado se forzará una sincronización (porque finalice el programa, se realice una llamada a un método de entrada de datos, ...) y entonces se volcará el contenido del buffer a la pantalla.

En este caso asumo que en la pantalla se mostrarán los resultados tras una espera de 1 segundo (0.1 segundos de espera por 10 números a mostrar).

Si ahora vemos el segundo caso:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    cout << i + 1 << endl;
    esperar(0.1);
}
```

Ahora estás llamando a `endl`. Si bien `endl` introduce, como todos sabemos, un salto de línea, este elemento posee otra funcionalidad añadida y es que fuerza a que el buffer de salida se sincronice. Esto obliga a que, tras introducir en el buffer un número este se vuelque a la consola.

Por la razón antes comentada, en el segundo caso observas que entre la aparición de cada número se realiza la espera de 0.1 segundos.

Imagino que lo que pretendes es corregir el primer caso. Para forzar la sincronización del buffer de salida puedes usar `std::flush`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    cout << i + 1 << " " << std::flush;
    esperar(0.1);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y la explicación. Esto soluciona el problema perfectamente.